# _get_pgmptr vs GetModuleFileName

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

What difference is there (if any) between these two?  MSDN is very unclear.

Here it sounds like they are equivalent:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But here it sounds like _pgmptr may not always give me a full path, but it doesn't really explain under what circumstances.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tza1y5f7.aspx

_pgmptr Seems far more attractive to me because I don't have to play buffer size guessing games with it.

Comment: [_pgmptr, _wpgmptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tza1y5f7.aspx): *"**When a program is not run from the command line**, _pgmptr might be initialized to the program name (the file's base name without the file name extension) or to a file name, relative path, or full path."* Does that not **explicitly** name the circumstances?

Comment: No it does not.  "Might be" is literally not explicit.

Comment: As far as documentation goes, you won't get any more explicit than this: When a program is not run from the command line, `_wpgmptr` may not contain a full path. If you don't care about contracts, and would rather develop against a particular implementation, you can dive right into reading the CRT source.

Comment: You are missing the point.  The documentation is contradictory: "The global variable _pgmptr is automatically initialized to the full path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path name of an executable file."

Comment: *"**When a program is run from the command interpreter**"*... How is that contradictory? May I direct your attention to the part right at the top, that says: *"Deprecated; use [_get_pgmptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24awhcba.aspx) and [_get_wpgmptr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2zbk054.aspx)."*

Comment: I can't help you if you can't see how the documentation on those two pages is contradictory.  I won't argue further with you in the comments.  If you want to post an answer please do so.

Comment: @BigSandwich MSDN documentation is often contradictory :)

Comment: @IInspectable: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24awhcba.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says that `_pgmptr` will always be a full path.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tza1y5f7.aspx) it says it might not be a full path if the program was not run from the command line.  So it does contradict itself.  I believe the claim that it might not be a full path is incorrect; it was perhaps true long ago and has just never been updated.

Comment: @BigSandwich: note that you do not need a buffer to use `_get_pgmptr` so that should be your preferred method.  (It doesn't copy the string into a buffer you provide, it copies a pointer to the string into a pointer you provide.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_pgmptr` is initialised using `GetModuleFileName` internally, so the answer is there's no difference - they will return the same string.

Comment: Also, _get_pgmptr really does return the value of _pgmptr.

Answer (score 4):

There at least one difference: `_get_pgmptr()` isn't available early in an application initialization, whilst `GetModuleFileName()` is. I've just been bitten by the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) because of this :(